# Button to pass a value to another page

Tags: html, mysql

Alright so I want my code to have a button that has a unique id attached to it. When the user presses this button, I want that ID attached to that button to be passed on to the next page.

The code I am using is below. I've tried many different ways but I haven't been able to figure out this issue. The button, on click, should go to the next page (add.php) and send with it the RoomID (which is from a mysql database). This is my first time using both php and html, so it probably looks atrocious.

`<td width=10%><a href='add.php' method='post' id=".htmlspecialchars($row['RoomID']).">Reserve</a></td>`

Below is the part of the code on the add.php that I'm having issues with. I've made a form in html that worked like a user submission form so I've been going off of that, so if this has no possible way of working, please enlighten me. I haven't been able to find anything. Thank you in advance!

`$RoomID=$_POST['RoomID']`

Answer (score 3):

You can pass value using query string.

```
<td width=10%><a href='add.php?RoomID=<?php echo $row['RoomID']; ?>' id=".htmlspecialchars($row['RoomID']).">Reserve</a></td>
```

You will get the value by through method on add.php page.

```
$RoomID=$_GET['RoomID'];
```

Comment: That seems to do something, but not the effect I was hoping for... curretly it's breaking my table